# The division of the element (texts) into two

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using code:

```
data = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[starts-with(@id, "popover")]/span[2]')
for list_data in data:
        print(list_data.get_attribute('innerText'))
```

I get several view items:

```
2019-03-29 - 2019-03-27

2019-02-25 - 2019-03-29

2019-01-24 - 2019-03-25
```

I would like to separate them.
Perhaps there is a team that divides the text into two? For example, I have 10 characters, and I can remove the first or last 5 characters
I will be glad to your ideas how to divide this element into 2 parts

**UPD:**

Ok, I want to get the output instead 2019-03-29 - 2019-03-27 this 2019-03-29

Comment: what is your desire output?

Comment: How does _remove the first or last 5 characters_ relates to _Selenium_? Am I missing something?

Comment: @DebanjanB : probably OP wants to get first 5 or last 5 chars from a string that is what I understood.

Comment: @KajalKundu How does even that relates to _Selenium_ to be tagged?

Comment: @DebanjanB he asked `For example.....` so still desired output is not mentioned

Comment: @ I have deleted my answer..since OP is not responding what he is looking after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this you want

```
dates =['2019-03-29 - 2019-03-27','2019-02-25 - 2019-03-29','2019-01-24 - 2019-03-25']
for date in dates:
    start_date, end_date = date.split(' - ')
    print(start_date, end_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case a `str.split(' - ')` is the most reasonable solution I can think of.

In general, you you want to divide any string in two pieces, I would do something like:

```
_string = 'aaaaaiiiii'
hl = int(len(_string)/2) #half len
print(_string[:hl])
print(_string[hl:])
```

output

```
aaaaa
iiiii
```

Answer (score 0):

Using following code you can do a 10 character split, modify the slicing part for reverse splitting of 10 characters.

```
    data = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[starts-with(@id, "popover")]/span[2]')
    for list_data in data:
        word = list_data.get_attribute('innerText')
        print([word[i:i+10] for i in range(0, len(word), 10)]) # 10 character split
```

Comment: 10 character split can give you this (2019-03-29)

Answer (score 0):

If you have list like following.

```
data=['2019-03-29 - 2019-03-27','2019-02-25 - 2019-03-29','2019-01-24 - 2019-03-25']
for list_data in data:
       print(list_data[:10]) ## first 10 characters
```

EDITED last 5 chars.

```
data=['2019-03-29 - 2019-03-27','2019-02-25 - 2019-03-29','2019-01-24 - 2019-03-25']
for list_data in data:
       print(list_data[-5:])
```

Comment: What if I need to get the last 5 characters?

Comment: @keepomen : check Edited section